# Is there a way to flush correlation IDs or channels after Aggregation?

Tags: spring-integration

My Spring Integration (with a HTTP inbound gateway) application has the following flow:

- The end-client POSTs an XML input message with a UUID for unique identification (let us call this XML, "whole") and other business elements
- A Splitter component breaks it down into smaller XMLs with each "part" XML having the same UUID as the "whole" XML
- The Aggregator aggregates the parts with some business logic along with a @CorrelationStrategy that uses the UUID of the incoming "part" messages

I am trying to explore a way to clear/flush the Aggregator's inputChannel or reset the Correlation Strategy after the correlation operation to enable different POST requests to reuse the UUIDs in the incoming "whole" XML input messages.

At this point, what is happening is that once a "whole" XML input message is processed successfully, if another HTTP POST sends a "whole" XML input message with the same UUID, the flow is hanging, probably because it is unable to understand what to do with the @CorrelationStrategy or is in a stale state in terms of UUIDs.

Frankly, the very definition of UUID means it has to be uniquely generated for every HTTP request but just wanted to accommodate a case where the end-client ends up sending the same UUID for every POST.

This is how my Aggregator class and its methods look:

```
@MessageEndpoint 
public class ProductAggregator {
...
...

@Aggregator(inputChannel="compositeMessagesForAggregation", 
outputChannel="upstreamResponses")
public Message<BusinessComposite> 
generateAggregatedResponse(List<Message<BusinessComposite>> 
listOfCompositeMessagesForAggregation) {
...
...
}

@CorrelationStrategy
public UUID correlateByUUID(Message<BusinessComposite> 
compositeMessageForAggregation) { 
...
...
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Sincerely,
Bharath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `expireGroupsUponCompletion` and `expireGroupsUponExpiry` to `true` on the aggregator to reuse the same correlation id; otherwise "late arriving" messages are discarded.

Comment: In the documentation and API for 4.3.8.RELEASE, it is somewhat unclear if this can be used as a part of the Annotation options - is this available only via XML-configuration?

Comment: That's just the aggregator - you need to show how you are wiring it into your integration flow. You can't do advanced configuration if you are using a simple component scan, you need to define the aggregator bean, or use the Java DSL.

Comment: Sure Gary, will use XML for better control. This brings me to a (rather simple) question assuming the flags are "true" - My application has a splitter and a task executor thread pool working on the splits meaning the original thread is lost. As we know, the aggregator is a Singleton and it keeps aggregating based based on correlation ID. Say User 1 sends a long running request with one UUID and a little while later, User 2 sends another with the same UUID, will the aggregator will end-up correlating responses for both (though they are different users and shouldn't be correlated)?

Comment: If the group still exists, a new message with the same correlation will be considered part of that group. Expiring the group is the only way for a new group to start. If you really need to deal with that situation, you need another solution - such as combining the "UUID" (which it's not) with the user id.

Comment: Got it! Totally with you on UUID having to be "unique" (programmatically generated) (which in this case, isn't so) - this is what I am slow-feeding to the consumers/business of my API and will implement your solution as a back-up in case the concept of a UUID's uniqueness isn't understood by them.